# Find documents in MongoDB by UUID (Convert ObjectId to UUID)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, uuid, objectid

I have to find documents in MongoDB by UUID but documents are stored with ObjectId. How can I convert UUID into ObjectId or vice versa? I use python and pymongo to query processing.

I found only one mention of this issue:

https://gist.github.com/enaeseth/5768348 -

there is a python script which converts ObjectID to UUID. But it doesn't work correctly. For example, it returns `'f940bd00-55c3-11e3-a447-00e4b0ce16e9'` instead of `'f940bd03-55c3-11e3-a4b0-ce16e9596447'` when processes `'52933322e4b0ce16e9596447'`. (I have sample of relative UUIDs and ObjectIds to test).

Could you help me to find other solution or to modify this script? Thanks a lot.

Comment: why do you need it to be a `uuid`? Can't you just store the `uuid` in a field and query for it in a similar way?

Comment: I have no possibility to modify data, just can retrieve. In mongoDB data is stored with ObjectId but I have list of documents' UUID, which have to use.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. If the documents use ObjectId for _id, where are you getting these UUIDs and how could they possibly have anything to do with MongoDB?

Comment: Data is stored in two databases - in mongodb with ObjectIds and in mysql DB with UUIDs. I need to retrieve information by merging MongoDB and Mysql DB data. And I don't know why this architecture is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Convert ObjectId to UUID**

```
import datetime as dt
from bson import ObjectId
from uuid import UUID


class UTC(dt.tzinfo):
    ZERO = dt.timedelta(0)

    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return self.ZERO

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return 'UTC'

    def dst(self, dt):
        return self.ZERO

UTC = UTC()
UUID_1_EPOCH = dt.datetime(1582, 10, 15, tzinfo=UTC)
UUID_TICKS_PER_SECOND = 10000000


def unix_time_to_uuid_time(dt):
    return int((dt - UUID_1_EPOCH).total_seconds() * UUID_TICKS_PER_SECOND)


def object_id_to_uuid(object_id):
    """
    Converts ObjectId to UUID

    :param object_id: some ObjectId
    :return: UUID
    """

    str_object_id = str(object_id)

    b = []
    for i in [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22]:
        b.append(int(str_object_id[i:i+2], 16))

    generation_time = ObjectId(str_object_id).generation_time.astimezone(UTC)
    time = unix_time_to_uuid_time(generation_time)
    time |= (b[4] >> 6) & 0x3

    most_sig_bits = str(hex(0x1000 | time >> 48 & 0x0FFF
                            | time >> 16 & 0xFFFF0000
                            | time << 32))[9:]

    least_sig_bits = str(hex(2 << 62
                             | (b[4] & 0x3F) << 56 | (b[5] & 0xFF) << 48
                             | (b[6] & 0xFF) << 40 | (b[7] & 0xFF) << 32
                             | (b[8] & 0xFF) << 24 | (b[9] & 0xFF) << 16
                             | (b[10] & 0xFF) << 8 | b[11] & 0xFF))[2:]

    return UUID('%s-%s-%s-%s-%s' % (most_sig_bits[:8], most_sig_bits[8:12], most_sig_bits[12:16],
                               least_sig_bits[0:4], least_sig_bits[4:]))
```

**Convert UUID to ObjectId**

```
import datetime as dt
from bson import ObjectId
import pytz


def get_timestamp_from_uuid(uuid_object):

    generation_time = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp((uuid_object.time - 0x01b21dd213814000) * 100 / 1e9)
    generation_time = generation_time.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)

    return int(generation_time.timestamp())


def get_timestamp_from_object_id(object_id):

    generation_time = object_id.generation_time
    return int(generation_time.timestamp())


def return_decimal_bytes(binary):

    binary = binary[2:]
    rest = len(binary) % 8

    if rest != 0:
        binary = '0'*(8 - rest) + binary
    bytes = {}

    for i in range(0, len(binary)//8):
        bytes[i] = binary[:8]
        binary = binary[8:]

    return bytes


def uuid_to_object_id(uuid_object):
    """
    Converts UUID to ObjectId

    :param uuid_object: UUID
    :return: ObjectId
    """

    uuid_to_bin = bin(int(uuid_object))
    parts_of_uuid = return_decimal_bytes(uuid_to_bin)

    timestamp_of_uuid = hex(get_timestamp_from_uuid(uuid_object))
    timestamp_of_uuid = timestamp_of_uuid.replace('0x', '')

    uuid_time = uuid_object.time

    fourth = int(parts_of_uuid[8], 2) & 0x3F | (uuid_time << 6)
    fourth = str(hex(fourth))[-2:]

    fifth = str(hex(int(parts_of_uuid[9], 2)))
    sixth = str(hex(int(parts_of_uuid[10], 2)))
    seventh = str(hex(int(parts_of_uuid[11], 2)))
    eighth = str(hex(int(parts_of_uuid[12], 2)))
    ninth = str(hex(int(parts_of_uuid[13], 2)))
    tenth = str(hex(int(parts_of_uuid[14], 2)))

    try:
        eleventh = str(hex(int(parts_of_uuid[15], 2)))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        eleventh = str(hex(1))

    def rep(el):
        if len(el) <= 3:
            return el.replace('x', '')
        else:
            return el.replace('0x', '')

    res = rep(fifth) + rep(sixth) + rep(seventh) + rep(eighth) + rep(ninth) + rep(tenth) + rep(eleventh)

    return ObjectId(timestamp_of_uuid + fourth + res)
```

[Refference](https://github.com/evgm/ObjectIdToUUID)